# Type from IntPtr handle

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Is it possible to obtain the [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object from an `IntPtr` type handle (that can be obtained by `Type.TypeHandle.Value`)?

Example:

```
TypeFromIntPtr(typeof(object).TypeHandle.Value) == typeof(object) //true
```

Edit: I am glad there are many helpful people that think I am trying to solve something else, but I am seeking the answer to this particular problem and I am really sure about it. I am sorry for not specifying it in the first place.

Edit #2: Type handle is a pointer that points to the structure that represents RTTI in the CLR. I don't want to read data from this structure, I want a way that returns the managed `Type` object for this. I need to "convert" the pointer to the object.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Of course. Converting an `IntPtr` representing a type handle to a `System.Type` instance. I've thought I made it clear.

Comment: That is absolutely clear. The question is why do you need it? It seems rather peculiar, and there might be other ways of tackling the problem if you tell us what is the problem you're dealing with, and not a specific implementation detail you need.

Comment: @IllidanS4 That's what we call XYProblem. Am pretty sure you're trying to solve a different problem, Where does that `IntPtr` comes from? What problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am trying to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Can you understand why we're asking you again and again? I strongly suspect you have a different problem and you're creating another problem. **Where does that `IntPtr` comes from?**

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Must I have a reason to need this problem solved? I seek an answer to this specific problem and no other.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Okay, if you insist on it, the `IntPtr` comes from the header of a GC-collected managed object. Is it clearer now?

Comment: You mustn't have anything. We simply want to provide the best possible solution to the problem, but the problem here is unclear.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov And I've already stated my problem. Thank you for trying to help me find the roots of this problem, but there are none, and I am sure about that.

Comment: Alright then. Have you looked into `Marshal.PtrToStructure`? Is the type known at compile-time?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The `IntPtr` is a type handle (basically unmanaged way of indetifying `Type` object). `Marshal.PtrToStructure` is a way of reading the data in a specific location to a structure. I already have the data (the type handle `IntPtr`). I don't want to read what's in the location the pointer points to, I want to "convert" to a `Type` object.

Comment: Do you know what type it is at compile time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We usually won't allow anyone to shoot their foot, but you seem to be insisting that you need to, and you know what you're doing.

Here's how you shoot your foot:

```
private static Type GetTypeFromHandle(IntPtr handle)
{
    var method = typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandleUnsafe", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (Type)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { handle });
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr handle = typeof(string).TypeHandle.Value;//Obtain handle somehow

    Type type = GetTypeFromHandle(handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted. I searched the Type class but I must've missed it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to calling an internal method is to abuse a TypedReference:

```
    private struct TypedReferenceAccess
    {
        public IntPtr Value;
        public IntPtr Type;
    }

    private static unsafe Type GetTypeFromTypeHandle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        TypedReferenceAccess tr = new TypedReferenceAccess()
        {
            Type = handle
        };
        return __reftype(*(TypedReference*)&tr);
    }
```

This of course relies on the layout of TypedReference so is really unsafe. But since getting the Type from a TypeHandle is really unsupported you will have to pick your poison if you really want to. Though I would say that I can't help but find it a bit weird that the native TypeHandle is exposed publicly, but without any way of going in the other direction.